# How create unistall url and icon url for chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have this code I have added it on **background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener("https://mywebsites.com");
chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL("https://mywebsites.com/unistall");
```

but it is not working. I really need help I'm not good at javascript and I hope to get help. Thanks

Comment: Review the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction): `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` takes a function as an argument.

Comment: thanks for your help, i have add noe just this code chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL("https://mywebsites.com/unistall"); and is working so now i need help only to add the link for icon, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` takes in a callback function, not a string.

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://mywebsites.com" });
    });`

onClicked method won't work if you have a popup page for your App.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#events

Comment: Thanks for your help